# Australian citizen working in the USA

Tags: usa, working, australian-citizens

I’m an Australian citizen looking to work in America for a working holiday, but I can’t find a visa that applies to me. I don’t have the qualifications for an E-3 or H-B1, and I wouldn’t be working in jobs that would fall under H-B2. Is there an option that would work for me?

Additionally, I work as a freelance developer. Would I be allowed to continue to work in America under the visa waiver program?

Comment: If you're young enough, there's a working holiday option for Canada, if that's close enough.  As far as I know, the US and Australia have no such arrangement (neither do Canada and the US for that matter).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**, there isn't.  The US and Australia do not have a working holiday visa arrangement, and the VWP explicitly does not permit work.

The closest option would be the [E-3 visa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-3_visa), but this is similar to the H-1B visa (minus the tight quotas) and requires a sponsoring employer in the United States that the visa is tied to, so it's not really practical for freelancing.

Comment: I think the J-1 visa is rather more similar to the working holiday visa than is the E-3 visa.

Answer (score 4):

There are [J-1 "exchange visitor"](https://j1visa.state.gov) programs that are used for seasonal workers.  These require a sponsor who will employ you; before and after the program you have a 30-day "grace period" during which you can travel around the US.  Some sponsors have made the news for keeping their employees in rather exploitative conditions, but others are legitimate.  I think this kind of program is rather more similar to a working holiday visa than is the E-3 visa.